# Android - best resolution for background image?

Tags: android, background, resolution

I found a few answers regarding the same question, but they're all about hdpi, mdpi,xhdpi and ldpi. But my app only has hdpi, mdpi, nodpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi. What resolutions are the best for these?

Comment: nodpi!? Is there such a thing? I would make one at the 800*480 for hdpi and then one each for the most popular resolutions for each category. Like another for 340*480 etc.

Comment: nodpi -> Resources for all densities. These are density-independent resources. The system does not scale resources tagged with this qualifier, regardless of the current screen's density.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have all the information that you need.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html